# Python repeating urllib request

Tags: python, urllib, turtle-graphics

I have this silly program that retrieves a random cat image and plays a meow sound:

```
import urllib.request
import turtle
import time
import playsound

screen = turtle.Screen()

url = 'https://cataas.com/cat/gif'
filename = "random-cat.gif"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)

screen.bgpic('random-cat.gif')

playsound.playsound('meow.mp3', True)

turtle.done()
```

However, if I want to repeat the code in a loop with a time delay, the image doesn't display at all:

```
screen = turtle.Screen()

while True:
    url = 'https://cataas.com/cat/gif'
    filename = "random-cat.gif"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)

    screen.bgpic('random-cat.gif')

    playsound.playsound('meow.mp3', True)

    time.sleep(5)

turtle.done()
```

Can someone please explain why this is and how to fix it? I'm thinking it might have to do with the way `time.sleep()` works.

Answer (score 0):

`turtle.done()` Never gets called because you never get out of the loop, you should render it and after every loop iteration

Answer (score 0):

I tested this (except for sound) and found a problem -- turtle *caches* images so using the same file name with a new image won't work!  We could fix this with code to rename the file after download with a counter, as well as file cleanup.  Or we can manipulate turtle's image cache behind the scene:

```
import urllib.request
import turtle
import playsound

url = 'https://cataas.com/cat/gif'
filename = 'random-cat.gif'
sound = 'meow.mp3'

def meow():
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)

    if screen.bgpic() == filename:
        screen._bgpics[filename] = screen._image(filename)

    screen.bgpic(filename)

    playsound.playsound(sound, True)

    screen.ontimer(meow, 5000)

screen = turtle.Screen()

meow()

turtle.done()
```

Comment: @Robin, I've updated my answer to get around an issue with image caching.  I've tested all but sound and it seems to work correclty.